# Adobe flex from a list componet to radio buttons

Tags: apache-flex, list, if-statement, adobe, radio-button

I have tried to do this many ways but for the life of me cannot think how to. Basically I have a list. When an item on the list is selected the radio button labels change. However, I want a label and text area to appear saying once the user has clicked on the radio button if it is right or not. 
Code so far: -

```
<s:VGroup x="103" y="130" width="123" height="125">
    <s:RadioButton id="RadioButton1" label="{data.QuestionsRadioButton1}" groupName="QuestionsTestRadioButtons" click="RadioButton1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:RadioButton label="{data.QuestionsRadioButton2}" groupName="QuestionsTestRadioButtons" click="radiobutton1_clickHandler(event)" />
    <s:RadioButton id="RadioButton3" label="{data.QuestionsRadioButton3}" groupName="QuestionsTestRadioButtons" click="radiobutton2_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

I will not post all the code as we will be here forever. However, is there a way maybe an if function? To say if the radio button clicked actually is the right answer or not?

Any suggestions would be helpful
Thank You

Comment: Without knowing your data structure; or how the radio buttons are being displayed how are we--as question answers on stack overflow--supposed to know whether the right item is clicked or not?  Then extend that to Flex; how is the framework supposed to know?  It won't unless you tell it. If you have dynamic questions/answers; you'll need to load up the correct answers somehow and them perform a compare with the selected answer.  Presumably you'll set a "value" on the Radio Button which you can use to compare to the "Correct" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt to draft a complete example:

**Questionaire.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayCollection id="questions">
            <local:Question text="It is raining …">
                <s:ArrayCollection>
                    <local:Answer text="Men"/>
                    <local:Answer text="Cats and dogs" correct="true"/>
                    <local:Answer text="Candy"/>
                </s:ArrayCollection>
            </local:Question>
            <local:Question text="The sky is …">
                <s:ArrayCollection>
                    <local:Answer text="Blue" correct="true"/>
                    <local:Answer text="Orange" correct="true"/>
                    <local:Answer text="Grey" correct="true"/>
                    <local:Answer text="Green"/>
                </s:ArrayCollection>
            </local:Question>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{questions}" itemRenderer="QuestionRenderer">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="24"/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>
</s:Application>
```

**QuestionRenderer.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:DataRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable("dataChange")]
            public function get question():Question {
                return data as Question;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="answerGroup"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:Label fontWeight="bold" text="{question.text}"/>

    <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{question.answers}">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:DataRenderer>
                    <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import spark.components.RadioButtonGroup;

                            public function get answerGroup():RadioButtonGroup {
                                return outerDocument.answerGroup;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                    <s:RadioButton groupName="answerGroup" label="{data.text}" value="{data}"/>
                </s:DataRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:DataGroup>

    <s:Label visible="{answerGroup.selectedValue}" text="This is {answerGroup.selectedValue.correct ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'}."/>
</s:DataRenderer>
```

**Question.as**

```
package {
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]
    [DefaultProperty("answers")]
    public class Question {
        public var text:String;
        public var answers:ArrayCollection;
    }
}
```

**Answer.as**

```
package {
    [Bindable]
    public class Answer {
        public var text:String;
        public var correct:Boolean = false;
    }
}
```